# How to solve $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{ 2x^2}{1-\cos x}$?

Tags: limits

I have a little doubt. I tried to solve this limit in two different ways, one works and the other doesn't but I don't understand why. I would really appreciate if someone could help me to understand where did I make the mistake.

Fist way (that works)
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2x^2}{1 - \cos x} \cdot \frac{1 + \cos x}{1 + \cos x} & = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2x^2 (1 + \cos x)}{\sin^2 x} \\
& = \lim_{x \to 0} 2 \cdot \frac{x^2}{\sin^2 x} \cdot (1 + \cos x) \\
& = 2 \cdot 1 \cdot 2 \\
& = 4.
\end{align*}

Second way (that doesn't work)

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2 x^2}{1 - \cos x} \cdot \frac{1 + \cos x}{1 + \cos x} & = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2 x^2 (1 + \cos x)}{(1 - \cos x)(1 + \cos x)} \\
& = \frac{0}{0}
\end{align*}

Comment: What you did in the second method is something very similar to $$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{ac}{bc}=\frac{a}{b}.$$
Why did you multiply and divide $\frac{a}{b}$ by $c$ then?

Comment: Yes, now I can see it doesn't make any sense cause it's like returning to the starting point!

Comment: Another note: You'll get a lot more out of this website if you can format your question in MathJax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second way, you ended with where you started. Since you cancel away $(1+\cos x)$ after you introduce them.

If you substitute the value in and you encounter $\frac{0}{0}$, it is in indeterminate form and L'hopital's rule is a useful tool.

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2x^2}{1-\cos x}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{d}{dx}(2x^2)}{\frac{d}{dx}(1-\cos x)}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{4x}{\sin x}=4$$

Comment: Did you apply L'Hospital twice

Comment: Either that or use the fact that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{\sin x}=1$.

Comment: Yep got that...

Answer (score 1):

Third way by Taylor's series

$$\cos x=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)$$

thus

$$\frac{2x^2}{1-\cos x}=\frac{2x^2}{1-1+\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)}=\frac{4}{1+o(1)}  \to4$$

thus

$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{2x^2}{1-\cos x}=4$$

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, by multiplying by $a/a$, you were able to rewrite the denominator. In the second, you just factored out the changes you'd made, reversing your first step.